# AWS Installing apache and FTP server

Tags: python, aws-sdk, boto3

I am using python and boto3 to automate the deployment of my AWS services and I want to automate the installation on apache and FTP server after launching my instance. However, apache and Ftp doesn't seem to install. I pass "update" into the aws instance once it launched. The instance is launch successfully but apache and FTP not installed

```html
class test(CreateVpc):
    def createec2(self, create_vpcid):
        ec2 = Ec2Services(create_vpcid.ec2_client)
  
    update = """sudo su
                 apt update -y
                 apt upgrade -y
                 apt install apache2 -y
                 apt install vsftpd -y """

    #launch instance
    ec2.launch_our_ec2_instance(amage_id, keypair_name, 1, 1, pub_security_group_id, create_vpcid.pub_subnetid,update)
```

Comment: What is this code and where is it being run? Are you passing it as User Data? Feel free to edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I cant put this as a comment. Though boto3, last I checked is the Amazon AWS SDK interface tool. It's interface with he launched EC2 VM. Ie if you cant do it from the Amazon AWS Console in the browser or using the AWS cli tools. Then you shouldnt expect to do it from the python SDK.

You could get the EC2 IP address information and issuing the command from SSH or a Configuration Mananagement utility (Ansible, Puppet, Salt)